# Apache PDFBox: Can I set font other than those present in PDType1Font

Tags: java, pdfbox

I can see only 4 fonts with variants in PDType1Font.
Is there any way I can use other / custom fonts?

PDFType1Font fonts

```
  public static final PDType1Font TIMES_ROMAN = new PDType1Font("Times-Roman");
    public static final PDType1Font TIMES_BOLD = new PDType1Font("Times-Bold");
    public static final PDType1Font TIMES_ITALIC = new PDType1Font("Times-Italic");
    public static final PDType1Font TIMES_BOLD_ITALIC = new PDType1Font("Times-BoldItalic");
    public static final PDType1Font HELVETICA = new PDType1Font("Helvetica");
    public static final PDType1Font HELVETICA_BOLD = new PDType1Font("Helvetica-Bold");
    public static final PDType1Font HELVETICA_OBLIQUE = new PDType1Font("Helvetica-Oblique");
    public static final PDType1Font HELVETICA_BOLD_OBLIQUE = new PDType1Font("Helvetica-BoldOblique");
    public static final PDType1Font COURIER = new PDType1Font("Courier");
    public static final PDType1Font COURIER_BOLD = new PDType1Font("Courier-Bold");
    public static final PDType1Font COURIER_OBLIQUE = new PDType1Font("Courier-Oblique");
    public static final PDType1Font COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE = new PDType1Font("Courier-BoldOblique");
    public static final PDType1Font SYMBOL = new PDType1Font("Symbol");
    public static final PDType1Font ZAPF_DINGBATS = new PDType1Font("ZapfDingbats");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load truetype fonts like this in Apache PDFBox 2.0.*:

```
PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("c:/windows/fonts/simhei.ttf"));
```

See also the [API documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDType0Font.html#load(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument,%20java.io.File)) and the [EmbeddedFonts.java example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/EmbeddedFonts.java?view=markup&sortby=date).

Comment: How can I get the text in bold with that loaded font?

Comment: The best is to load a bold font. This is usually available. The second best (won't look so good) is to call `pageContentStream.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.FILL_STROKE)`.

Comment: Thank you. It helps