# Register additional fonts for PDFBox rendering

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-rendering, fontbox

Since 2.0 PdfBox can render embedded fonts. However I can not influence what PDFs come in and there are certain PDFs without embedded fonts. In that case the fonts installed on the system are used. Now due to some restriction I can also not install fonts on that (server) system. So it would be nice if there is the possibility to register additional fonts supplied as a jar file in the classpath.
I tried

```
PDType0Font.load(...)
PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(...)
```

however this only seems to be for creating new documents. I stumbled over this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118074/adding-fonts-to-apache-pdfbox) however the solution was to use the embedded fonts.
So I thought about writing my own `FontDirFinder` (even though the name would not be 100% correct) but the implementation in the FontFileFinder class (method) `determineDirFinder()` doesn't allow (yet) to register an own `Finder`. So a patch would be necessary.

But before working on that I would like to ask whether there is some existing possibility to make font files known to PDFBox (without embedding or coping to/using system fonts)?

**So basically I can not change the PDFs and not the server font directory/infrastructure. But I can supply additional fonts as part of the deployment (part of a jar file etc).** (and I look for a way to get PdfBox to recognize these)

Comment: "whether there is some existing possibility to make font files known to PDFBox" - copy thenm into your font directory. Or on linux create a directory .fonts in  your user directory.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I clarified my question...

Comment: So what you're asking is to include font files in the jar itself. That means you'll have to change the project.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes this is the only thing I can influence. Basically I can not change the PDFs and not the server infrastructure. But I can influence the deployment...(thus e.g. add a jar containing certain fonts)